# how I can create a timer that works simultaneously with a game in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, loops, timer

I am creating a game called "Point and Fame", which is based on a combination of numbers to guess that the compiler extracts it random, I have to add a timer that will print at the same time the game is running, I have understood that i need to create a multithread process which i don't know how to do it.

If there's another way to put the timer in the game, or make to loops run at the same time will help me a lot.

Comment: This depends on what platform you're working on.

Comment: If you don't want to thread, examine a system timer every time you hit the end of a game loop.  If it has increased enough, update your timer value and have it reprint.  Works as long as you don't "block" in your code anywhere (like waiting for input.)

Comment: you don't necessarily need to go multithreaded. if you can get your OS to give you a regular timer callback at a sufficient rate, you can accomplish everything relative to that rate. don't just throw threads at a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had read this article before don't know if it will help but just check [this](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/03/14/create-a-timer/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/* This is our thread function.  It is like main(), but for a thread */
void *threadFunc(void *arg)
{
    char *str;
    int i = 0;

    str=(char*)arg;

    while(i < 10 )
    {
        usleep(1);
        printf("threadFunc says: %s\n",str);
        ++i;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{    
    pthread_t pth;  // this is our thread identifier
    int i = 0;

    /* Create worker thread */
    pthread_create(&pth,NULL,threadFunc,"processing...");

    /* wait for our thread to finish before continuing */
    pthread_join(pth, NULL /* void ** return value could go here */);

    while(i < 10 )
    {
        usleep(1);
        printf("main() is running...\n");
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```